# How to write query of queries in HQL (hibernate)

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I'm trying to SUM some data via query of queries.  Its a fairly complicated sql query over complicated relationships that I'd like to translate into HQL.

I'll use a simplified version of the data relationships to make discussion easier.

So how could I translate this into HQL? Is query of queries even possible in HQL?

## Example:

Suppose we have a Movie Critic that reviews movies online, and we want to return totals for the number of movies he's reviewed, the number of movies he loved, & the number of movies he hates.

#### Tables:

- Critic
- Movie
- Review (link table between Critic & Movie with LoveFlag, if LoveFlag is false he hates the movie)

#### SQL Query:

(this is a made up scenario, the solution i'm working on is for facility management.  I wrote this query on stack overflow, so there very well could be flaws in it.)

> SELECT criticSummary.id
>       , COUNT(criticSummary.reviewId) as totalReviews
>       , SUM(criticSummary.isLoved) as totalLoved
>       , SUM(criticSummary.isHated) as totalHated
>
> FROM (
>
> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT critic.id AS id, 
>     review.id AS reviewId, 
>     review.isLoved AS isLoved, 
>     CASE WHEN review.isLoved = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS isHated
>
> FROM [critic] critic
>
> INNER JOIN [review] review
> ON (
>     review.criticId = critic.id
>     AND review.active = 1
> )
>
> WHERE critic.active = 1
> ```
>
> ) AS criticSummary
>
> GROUP BY criticSummary.id

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use HQL? You have some options to simplify things:

**1 Hibernate Formula Fields in Critic Entity**

```
@Formula("select count(*) from reviews where id = id and loved = 1")
public int totalMoviesLoved;

@Formula("select count(*) from reviews where id = id and loved = 0")
public int totalMoviesHated;

public int getTotalMoviesReviewed(){
    return get totalMoviesHated + totalMoviesLoved;
}
```

**2 Create a Database View**

Create a Database view, say critic_summary_data
Create an entity mapped to this view (works just the same as a table)

Map this in Critic Entity

```
@OneToOne
private CriticSummaryData summaryData;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply.  Quick response to #2: Unfortunately my boss does not want me to use a view, I had suggested it. Question to #1: It looks like this would generate nested sql queries.  Is this correct? When I wrote the original query, I used nested queries in the SELECT statement, and performance was terrible due to the large number of relationships in the query.